# MYSQL How to copy data from one column to another

Tags: mysql

Is there a mysql command that can alter a table so that my column (owner) can have the same values as the primary key (id)?

This is basically what I want:

```
id  |  title  |  body  |  owner | 
----------------------------------
1                          1
2                          2   
3                          3
4                          4
```

I want this to be automatic so that I don't have to find the "id" value and then insert that value into the owner column using php. I'm planning on using the "owner" column as a foreign key.

Note: The id column is the primary key, and has auto increment.

Thanks everyone (:

Comment: Any specific reason why id column itself cannot be used as foreign key?

Comment: is it ok if you do it with a query ? or do you want this to happen automatically ?

Answer (score 3):

two solutions:

1. Do it mannualy
2. Create a trigger

For the manual solution:

```
update tbl set owner = id;
```

For the trigger solution:

```
 delimiter $$
 create trigger trgr after insert on tbl 
 for each row begin
     update tbl
     set owner = id
 end;
 $$
 delimiter ;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: by the way... why don't you use `id` instead of `owner`? I simply can't think of a situation in which I need the same value in another column of the same table

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
UPDATE test1 SET project = id
```

It's simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name SET owner=id
```

after inserting the new row this is sufficient i think